# Finning columns with 1 or 0 depending upon if the searched string exists

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to replace the string in a column with value 0 or 1  by searching for a specific word. The column consists of long sentences. How can I achieve that?

I tried searching for the words in the column but all I have been able to do far is check how many times the words exist or print the boolean values only.

```
xl['values'].fillna(0)
if (xl['values'].str.contains('ALEXEI').any()):
    xl['values'].str.replace(xl['values'],'1')
```

Comment: `xl['values']=xl['values'].str.contains('ALEXEI',na=False).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
xl['values']=np.where(xl['values'].str.contains('ALEXEI',na=False),1,0)
```

I find np.where() to be much quicker than any pandas method to do this kind of thing. The first argument is your search, the second is the returned value for True and the second for false.